# $emit, $broadcast, prototypical inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Still on the basics of AngularJS, i understand the concepts, however, just looking at custom events,

```
$emit
```

and

```
$broadcast
```

for nested controller..

According to the docs, $emit bubbles the event, ie. passes it up the chain, for nested controllers,

My question, is,   how is this different to just simply calling a function from the parent controller (prototypical inheritance). Or have i miss understood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, you can't always be certain that your direct parent, is the one you want to call. It's easy to break your code with that kind of anti-pattern.

And you must agree that

```
$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.doSomething();
```

Is pretty ugly.

Instead you can `$emit` an event upwards, now it doesn't matter how far up the chain your parent controller is, as long as it is listening and reacting.

This gives you nice **loose coupling** between controllers, and just acts like a message pump.

The same goes for `$broadcast`, just downwards instead, and here I would argue that it is even more important.

Answer (score 0):

`$emit` helps you to pass event to the parent controllers.

You can't use `$controller('ParentController', {scope: scope})` in all your child controllers to inherit the properties. To make the code clean and loosely coupled, $emit will help you to achieve that.

Assume you have three levels of hierarchy and you want the child controller to update the value of a particular parent controller. If you are going to do that via prototype chain, you need to inherit that particular controller using  `$controller('ParentController', {scope: scope})`  but `$emit` will avoid that. You need not know which parent controller. instead just emit the event.

In the appropriate parent controller where you want to read the data, use

```
$scope.$on("eventname", function(event, data) {
   // update value here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the example of a child controller with many parents or a parent controller with many children. Should the developer need to maintain a list of children within the parent to invoke a function on each of them. $emit and $broadcast are utilities to allow a loose-coupling messaging along the lines of an Observer pattern. If all parents in the hierarchy need to know that a child controller has done some task or needs some task dome on its behalf then is can just generate an event and interested parties can listen.

Data can also be passed removing the need for controllers to share data on the inherited scope.